# Recursive rename to remove the end of multiple filenames in a folder

Tags: command-line, rename, mv

I would like to rename multiple files in one folder.

I am looking to keep all of the original filenames minus the tag at the end.

for example I have:

```
FILE1[file].doc

FILE2[file].doc

FILE3[file].doc
```

etc

I want to remove `[file]` from all files in the folder recursively, and would like to do so from the command line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Are all the tags the same, or it could be anything within the brackets just before the file extension?

Comment: Are these just generic examples, or you have filenames that are actually different ?

Comment: As you're a new user, don't forget to accept the answer that you found most helpful by clicking the grey round check button on the left of it. You can learn more about how our site works by investing only two minutes into taking the little [tour]. Thank you and welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I assume your current working directory is the one that contains the files you want to rename, like in this example:

```
$ tree

.
├── FILE1[file].doc
├── FILE2[file].doc
├── FILE3[file].doc
└── subdir
    ├── FILE1[file].doc
    ├── FILE2[file].doc
    └── FILE3[file].doc
```

Now you can run the following command to recursively list all files in the current directory with the extension `.doc`:

```
$ find . -type f -iname '*.doc'

./subdir/FILE3[file].doc
./subdir/FILE2[file].doc
./subdir/FILE1[file].doc
./FILE3[file].doc
./FILE2[file].doc
./FILE1[file].doc
```

To rename all those files and remove the `[file]` part right before the `.doc` extension (if it is present) from each name, run this:

```
$ find . -type f -iname '*.doc' -exec rename -v 's/\[file\](?=\.doc$)//' {} +

./subdir/FILE3[file].doc renamed as ./subdir/FILE3.doc
./subdir/FILE2[file].doc renamed as ./subdir/FILE2.doc
./subdir/FILE1[file].doc renamed as ./subdir/FILE1.doc
./FILE3[file].doc renamed as ./FILE3.doc
./FILE2[file].doc renamed as ./FILE2.doc
./FILE1[file].doc renamed as ./FILE1.doc
```

This executes the command `rename -v 's/\[file\](?=\.doc$)//' FILES`, where `FILES` is replaced with the list of files returned by the `find` command shown above.

What the `rename 's/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/'` does is to apply the regular expression pattern `\[file\](?=\.doc$)` (matches the exact string "[file]" if followed by the exact string ".doc" at the end of the line) to each of the specified file names. If it matches, that matching part of the file name is replaced with the replacement string, which is empty in our case.

Comment: Thankyou, Byte Commander, this command worked a treat. If possible could you just explain to me a few things about it? What does the -v after rename do, and is the replacement string here ----->  {} +

Comment: The `-v` option of `rename` means "verbose" and makes it print a line of output for every file it renames. You can omit it if you want to run the command quietly. The `{} +` is part of `find`'s `-exec` option. Everything after the `-exec` in the line is the command that shall be called with the search results as argument. The `{}` is the placeholder where the result file name(s) will be inserted and `+` means to insert many file names into the same command at once, while `\;` would mean to call the command separately for each single file name. Learn more by typing `man rename` and `man find`.

Answer (score 0):

Python approach, with `re.split()` and `os.rename()`.

```
$ ls
FILE1[file].doc  FILE2[file].doc  FILE3[file].doc
$ python -c "import os,re;[os.rename(f,'.'.join(re.split('\[|\]|\.',f)[::3])) for f in os.listdir('.')]"                 

$ ls
FILE1.doc  FILE2.doc  FILE3.doc
```

What happens here is that we loop over each filename in current working directory as provided by `os.listdir()` function, use `re.split()` to break down filename into list of strings using multiple separators, extract first and last string and make new name out of those two using `'.'.join()` function. The rest is simply `os.rename(old,new)`

Note that this is simple approach and doesn't protect against renaming directories or other stray files that you might have in that folder.